# php 5.3.13 ffmpeg Windows 7 64bit Not working wamp server

Tags: php, ffmpeg, 64-bit, wampserver

I am facing following issue during installing the ffmpeg on the windows 7 64-bit machine using WampServer Version 2.2 with php 5.3.13 and ffmpeg extension 32-Bit

I didn't find ffmpeg ext. 32-bit..

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: it's possible that the php_ffmpeg.dll you are using is not valid for your php version - where did you get it?

Comment: So, its mean there is no solution for this issue

Comment: Why on earth did you 5 people choose to migrate this question? It's about a dev tool (WAMP), which is on-topic here, per your FAQ. It's clearly off topic for Server Fault. Think before you migrate in the future. There's currently a 47% rate of rejected migrations from here to there because of thoughtless migrations like this

Comment: A useful question. Incorrectly closed IMHO.